# Помогите доработать регулярное выражение

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Нужно перевести строку из CamelCase в snack_case. Сейчас у меня работает следующий вариант:  `Regex.Replace(str, @"(?<!^)(?=[A-Z])", "_").ToLower()`, но проблема в том, сокращения в верхнем регистре тоже разделяются нижней чертой: **"WordWordURL" => "word_word_u_r_l".**

Как доработать регулярное выражение, что бы он не реагировал на подряд идущие символы в верхнем регистре, и результат был таким: **"word_word_url"**

Comment: Используйте `Regex.Replace(str, @"([a-z])([A-Z])", "$1_$2").ToLower()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы добавляете подчеркивание перед каждой большой буквой, если она не стоит первая. Добавляйте подчеркивание перед каждой большой буквой, если она стоит после маленькой буквы или цифры

```
Regex.Replace(str, @"(?<=[a-z0-9])(?=[A-Z])", "_").ToLower()
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте такой вариант

```
Regex.Replace(str, @"(?<!^|[A-Z])(?=[A-Z])", "_").ToLower()
```

Тест https://regex101.com/r/iHQTMl/1

Answer (score 1):

А почему именно регулярка? Кодом же вроде и понятней и быстрее

```
string FromCamelToSnake(string input)
{
    var q = new Queue<char> ();

    for(int i=0; i<input.Length; i++)
    {
        if (i > 0
            && char.IsLetter(input[i])
            && char.IsUpper(input[i])
            && char.IsLetter(input[i - 1]) 
            && char.IsLower(input[i - 1]))
        {
            q.Enqueue('_');         
        }

        if (char.IsLetter(input[i]))
            q.Enqueue(char.ToLower(input[i]));
        else q.Enqueue(input[i]);
    }

    return new string(q.ToArray());
}
```

Comment: А чем быстрей и проще? Писать целую функцию, ни разу не быстрей. Понятней? Мне кажется данное регулярное выражение не такое большое и сложное что бы его не понять, ежели просматривать 10 строк кода...

Comment: Быстрей по скорости работы. То, что я вам написал, работает за линейное время. Регулярка будет работать помедленней. Ну и это вам, автору регулярки, все понятно в ней. Но кто будет работать с кодом после вас не факт что регулярку поймет лучше, чем 10 строк элементарного кода. Я просто много работал с регулярками, как и правил их после других людей, потому сам исаользую их и рекомендую другим только если есть на то очевидные и веские причины. А если есть возможность кодом строку обработать - это почти всегда быстрее будет работать, чем регулярка.